# Sharing the connection object between variuos database queries

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

i am writing the JDBC tier for application .

I am acquiring the connection object from pool and do the stuff and return the connection to pool and

Up until now, I am sharing connection object at method scope and executing exact one query.

but now i want to execute the two queries using same connection , so  i have foll. doubts on my mind , please help solving same

- as connection is shared , after executing the first query , will it affect the execution of second query?
- First query has a resultSet and second query is excecuted and also has a resultSet, Will this affect the resultSet of former or later?
- If is yes to all then how many queries i can execute on a connection?

More info :

I am using

- MYSQL 5.5 Database and its driver
- Apache DBCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as connection is shared , after executing the first query , will it affect the execution of second query?

NO

> First query has a resultSet and second query is excecuted and also has a resultSet, Will this affect the resultSet of former or later?

NO unless both have the same resultset ;)

> If is yes to all then how many queries i can execute on a connection?

Not applicable as the answer to previous question is a NO.( But still you can execute as many queries as you want )

Comment: so, on Connection i can create many Statements and execute many query. With no issues, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on how many queries you can execute on any database connection, u can use the same connection for firing as many queries as possible.

what i would do?

create a single connection object and use it across my application.